# Getting the current iframe's body reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm working on modal windows. When I click on a hyperlink in the main page, I need to show a modal window. This modal window I prepared using divs and one iframe. iFrame is used to show the source. Now in this modal window, I have another hyperlink to click which again opens a new modal window. This goes on.

Every time when I click on hyperlink, i want to create a new modal window in that provided iframe's src file itself. How to achieve this ?

TIA.

[image: modal windows to built]

Comment: What you mean by "in that provided iframe's src file itself"? Can't understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Every time I want to create a new modal window on top of the previous one. For this I need to create the divs and iframe in the previous modal window - nothing but I need to add these divs and iframe elements in the source file I provided in the iframe of the previous modal window.

Comment: If you click on a hyperlink inside an iframe, you still want it to open a modal window in the main page?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Please check the image placed. This is what my requirement is...

Comment: @SeanHogan Please check the image placed. This is what my requirement is...

Comment: @Sriram The picture makes it clear. Can each iframe load the script that supports creating the modal window?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a simple java script file which creates div and iframe in your pages and frames. This script file will have all the necessary methods and a class to access these methods separately in each of the frame.

For example you can have the script file like

```
MyClass = function(){
 this.var1, this.var2; // To store values separately in each frame.
 this.myMethod = function(){
      // Function body
 }
}
```